# Implementing the Adams Bashforth Moulton Method in Python

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods

I am currently working on implementing the Adams Bashforth Moulton Method for solving a pendulum problem.

My current code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

#####################################################################################
# DEF func
#####################################################################################
def func(y,t):

    n=y.size
    f=np.zeros(6)

    xp=np.array([y[3],y[4],y[5]])[np.newaxis]

    mass=1.
    F1=0.
    F2=0.
    F3=-mass*9.8
    F=np.array([F1,F2,F3])[np.newaxis]

    phix=2.*y[0]
    phiy=2.*y[1]
    phiz=2.*y[2]
    G=np.array([phix,phiy,phiz])[np.newaxis]

    H=2.*np.eye(3)
    lambd=(mass*np.dot(xp,np.dot(H,xp.T))+np.dot(F,G.T))/np.dot(G,G.T)

    f[0]=y[3]
    f[1]=y[4]
    f[2]=y[5]
    for k in range(0,3):
        f[k+3]=(F[0,k]-lambd*G[0,k])/mass

    return f

def dF_matrix(y):

    n=y.size
    dF=np.zeros((6,6))

    xp=np.array([y[3],y[4],y[5]])[np.newaxis]

    mass=1.
    F1=0.
    F2=0.
    F3=-mass*9.8
    F=np.array([F1,F2,F3])[np.newaxis]

    phix=2.*y[0]
    phiy=2.*y[1]
    phiz=2.*y[2]
    G=np.array([phix,phiy,phiz])[np.newaxis]

    H=2.*np.eye(3)
    lambd=(mass*np.dot(xp,np.dot(H,xp.T))+np.dot(F,G.T))/np.dot(G,G.T)

    dF[0,3]=1
    dF[1,4]=1
    dF[2,5]=1
    dF[3,0]=(y[0]*F1+2*lambd)/mass
    dF[3,1]=(y[0]*F2)/mass
    dF[3,2]=(y[0]*F3)/mass
    dF[3,3]=phix*y[3]
    dF[3,4]=phix*y[4]
    dF[3,5]=phix*y[5]
    dF[4,0]=(y[1]*F1)/mass
    dF[4,1]=(y[1]*F2+2*lambd)/mass
    dF[4,2]=(y[1]*F3)/mass
    dF[4,3]=phiy*y[3]
    dF[4,4]=phiy*y[4]
    dF[4,5]=phiy*y[5]
    dF[5,0]=(y[2]*F1)/mass
    dF[5,1]=(y[2]*F2)/mass
    dF[5,2]=(y[2]*F3+2*lambd)/mass
    dF[5,3]=phiz*y[3]
    dF[5,4]=phiz*y[4]
    dF[5,5]=phiz*y[5]

    return dF

#####################################################################################
# PYTHON script:
# Solve ODE for pendulum problem
#####################################################################################
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

### Forward Euler Method

def forward_Euler(function, y_matrix, time):
    y = np.zeros((np.size(time), np.size(y_matrix)))
    y[0, :] = y_matrix

    for i in range(len(time) - 1):
        dt = time[i + 1] - time[i]
        y[i + 1, :] = y[i, :] + np.asarray(function(y[i, :], time[i])) * dt

    return y

### Modified Euler Method

def modified_Euler(function, y_matrix, time):
    y = np.zeros((np.size(time), np.size(y_matrix)))
    y[0, :] = y_matrix

    for i in range(len(time) - 1):
        dt = time[i + 1] - time[i]
        k1 = np.asarray(function(y[i, :], time[i]))
        k2 = np.asarray(function(y[i, : + k1], time[i]))
        y[i + 1, :] = y[i, :] + (k1 + k2) / 2

    return y

### Adams-Bashforth  2nd order

def Adams_Bash_2nd(function, y_matrix, time):
    y = np.zeros((np.size(time), np.size(y_matrix)))
    y[0, :] = y_matrix

    for i in range(len(time) - 1):
        dt = time[i + 1] - time[i]
        f_1 = function(y[i, :], time[i])
        f_2 = function(f_1, time[i])
        y[i + 1, :] = y[i, :] + dt * f_1 + ((dt**2)/2) * f_2

    return y

### Adams Bashforth Moulton Method

def Adams_Moulton(function, y_matrix, time):
    y = np.zeros((np.size(time), np.size(y_matrix)))
    y[0, :] = y_matrix

### predictor formula

    for i in range(len(time) - 1):
        dt = time[i + 1] - time[i]
        f_1 = function(y[i, :], time[i])
        f_2 = function(f_1, time[i])
        y[i + 1, :] = y[i, :] + dt * f_1 + ((dt**2)/2) * f_2

### Corrector formula

    for i in range(len(time-1)):
        dt = time[i + 1] - time[i]
        k_1 = 9 * (function(y[i, :], time[i+1]))
        k_2 = 19 * (function(y[i, :], time[i]))
        k_3 = 5 * (function(y[i, :], time[i-1]))
        k_4 = (function(y[i, :], time[i-2]))

        # === ERROR HAPPENS HERE ===
        y[i + 1, :] = y + (dt/24) * (k_1 + k_2 - k_3 + k_4)

    return y

# initial condition
y0=np.array([0.0,1.0,0.0,0.8,0.0,1.2])

print('ODE Python ..')

time_start = time.clock()
nt = 500
# time points
t = np.linspace(0,25,nt)
# solve ODE
y1 = odeint(func,y0,t)
time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
print('elapsed time',time_elapsed)
# compute residual:
r=y1[:,0]**2+y1[:,1]**2+y1[:,2]**2-1
rmax1=np.max(np.abs(r))
print('error',rmax1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(y1[:,0],y1[:,1],y1[:,2], 'gray')

plt.show()

# print ODE Euler Method

time_start = time.clock()
nt = 500
# time points
t = np.linspace(0, 25, nt)
# solve ODE
y1 = forward_Euler(func, y0, t)
print(y1)
time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
print('elapsed time', time_elapsed)
# compute residual:
r = y1[:, 0] ** 2 + y1[:, 1] ** 2 + y1[:, 2] ** 2 - 1
rmax1 = np.max(np.abs(r))
print('error', rmax1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(y1[:, 0], y1[:, 1], y1[:, 2], 'gray')

plt.show()

### Modified Euler method

time_start = time.clock()
nt = 500
# time points
t = np.linspace(0, 25, nt)
# solve ODE
y1 = forward_Euler(func, y0, t)
print(y1)
time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
print('elapsed time', time_elapsed)
# compute residual:
r = y1[:, 0] ** 2 + y1[:, 1] ** 2 + y1[:, 2] ** 2 - 1
rmax1 = np.max(np.abs(r))
print('error', rmax1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(y1[:, 0], y1[:, 1], y1[:, 2], 'gray')

plt.show()

### Adams-Bashforth 2nd order

time_start = time.clock()
nt = 500
# time points
t = np.linspace(0, 25, nt)
# solve ODE
y1 = Adams_Bash_2nd(func, y0, t)
print(y1)
time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
print('elapsed time', time_elapsed)
# compute residual:
r = y1[:, 0] ** 2 + y1[:, 1] ** 2 + y1[:, 2] ** 2 - 1
rmax1 = np.max(np.abs(r))
print('error', rmax1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(y1[:, 0], y1[:, 1], y1[:, 2], 'gray')

plt.show()

### Adams-Moulton 1st order

# time_start = time.clock()
nt = 500
# time points
t = np.linspace(0, 25, nt)
# solve ODE
y1 = Adams_Moulton(func, y0, t)
print(y1)
# time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
# print('elapsed time', time_elapsed)
# compute residual:
r = y1[:, 0] ** 2 + y1[:, 1] ** 2 + y1[:, 2] ** 2 - 1
rmax1 = np.max(np.abs(r))
print('error', rmax1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(y1[:, 0], y1[:, 1], y1[:, 2], 'gray')

plt.show()

exit()
```

My fucntion adam_moulton() keeps returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/solve_pendulum.py", line 249, in <module>
    y1 = Adams_Moulton(func, y0, t)
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Documents/solve_pendulum.py", line 148, in Adams_Moulton
    y[i + 1, :] = y + (dt/24) * (k_1 + k_2 - k_3 + k_4)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (500,6) into shape (6)
```

What is wrong in my thought process for implementing this multistep method?

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Needless to say, we don't have the line numbers here. Do please indicate the location next time.

Comment: Sorry my IDE has that encoded in, how do I add the line numbers?

Comment: We don't need the line numbers, just the location, e.g. by placing a comment in your source code. This time I've added it myself already (I just searched for `dt/24` so it wasn't *that* hard to find, but it is a bit much to ask every reader to do the same).

Comment: Ah I see, Thank you! Sorry about that, It's difficult to figure out the formatting on here sometimes.

Comment: You're performing essentially `y[i + 1, :] = y` and that can't work since the dimensions are incompatible. Did you mean `y[i + 1, :] = y[i] + ...`?

Comment: so if I said y[i+, :] = y[i] that would work?

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error on line 147 that says "index 500 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 500"

Comment: That's because you loop over `range(len(time-1))` which should be `range(len(time) - 1)` instead (the former works because `time` is a numpy array, so the subtraction happens element-wise.

Comment: So I got it to run but it doesn't really accomplish much

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Your Adams-Bashford 2 does not look like any Adams-Bashford method, one would expect to find `y[i+1]=y[i]+0.5*dt*(3*f[i]-f[i-1])`. How you got the square of `dt` in the context of a linear multistep method is mysterious. Note that you need to find `y[1]` by some other means. Also, your code should reflect that the explicit Adams-Bashford step is the predictor to the implicit Adams-Moulton step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function definition for the pendulum in Cartesian coordinates, a particle moving under gravity and the constraint `|x|^2=L^2=const.`, can be written much shorter as

```py
def func(y,t):

    x,v = y[:3],y[3:6]
    grav = np.array([0., 0., -9.8 ])
    lambd = (grav.dot(x)+v.dot(v))/x.dot(x)

    return np.concatenate([v, grav - lambd*x] )

# initial condition
y0=np.array([0.0,1.0,0.0,0.8,0.0,1.2])
```

As long as no friction term is included, the mass cancels out and need not be considered in the equations.

An inefficient implementation (no use of Jacobian and Newton-like steps) of the 4th order Adams-Moulton PECE method is

```py
def Adams_Moulton_4th(function, y_matrix, time):
    y = np.zeros((np.size(time), np.size(y_matrix)))
    y[0] = y_matrix
### bootstrap steps with 4th order one-step method
    dt = time[1] - time[0]
    y[1] = RK4_step(function,y[0], time[0], dt, N=4)
    y[2] = RK4_step(function,y[1], time[1], dt, N=4)
    y[3] = RK4_step(function,y[2], time[2], dt, N=4)

    f_m2 = function(y[0], time[0])
    f_m1 = function(y[1], time[1])
    f_0 = function(y[2], time[2])
    f_1 = function(y[3], time[3])
    for i in range(3,len(time) - 1):
    ### first shift the "virtual" function value array so that
    ### [f_m3, f_m2, f_m1, f_0] corresponds to [ f[i-3], f[i-2], f[i-1], f[i] ]
        f_m3, f_m2, f_m1, f_0 = f_m2, f_m1, f_0, f_1
    ### predictor formula 4th order [ 55/24, -59/24, 37/24, -3/8 ]
        y[i+1] = y[i] + (dt/24) * (55*f_0 - 59*f_m1 + 37*f_m2 - 9*f_m3)
        f_1 = function(y[i+1], time[i+1])
    ### Corrector formula 4th order [ 3/8, 19/24, -5/24, 1/24 ]
        y[i+1] = y[i] + (dt/24) * (9*f_1 + 19*f_0 - 5*f_m1 + f_m2)
        f_1 = function(y[i+1], time[i+1])
    return y
```

and results in with `nt=2500` steps in a radius error of `2.39e-05` with a plot that is close to the reference solution by `odeint`.

[image: 3D plots of the pendulum integration]

The classical RK4 method used in the bootstrapping process was implemented as

```py
def RK4_step(f,y,t,dt, N=1):
    dt /= N;
    for k in range(N):
        k1=f(y,t)*dt; k2=f(y+k1/2,t+dt/2)*dt; k3=f(y+k2/2,t+dt/2)*dt; k4=f(y+k3,t+dt)*dt;
        y, t = y+(k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)/6, t+dt        
    return y
```

Comment: where is the RK4() function from?

Comment: This is just the standard RK4 method, or N iterations of size dt/N of it. You probably do not need the loop, that is, N=1 should be sufficient. I had earlier an index error where I tried to correct the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm sorry this is one of first Numerical Methods classes and understanding how to implement the jacobian matrix in this doesn't make too much sense to me so far. I've been trying to look at how RK4 works from some youtube videos but translating it to python has been difficult thusfar

Comment: Thank you by the way this is amazing!